# "Uncaught TypeError: this._isDateType is not a function" within Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5

I've got every time a type error that a function definition could not be found. The code looks as follow:

```
return BaseController.extend("ch.micarna.weightprotocol.controller.Calendar", {
  onInit: function () {
    console.log(this._isDateType(new Date()));
    let oHbox = this.byId("calendar-container");
    let oTodayDate = new Date();
    let oEndDate = this._getLastDayOfMonth(oTodayDate);
  },

  _getLastDayOfMonth: (oBegin) => {
    if (this._isDateType(oBegin)) {
      throw new TypeError("The given parameter is not type of date.");
    }
    return new Date(oBegin.getFullYear(), oBegin.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  },

  _isDateType: (oDate) => {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(oDate) === "[object Date]";
  },

});
```

The problem is the `_isDateType` function that could not be found when it is called inside the `_getLastDayOfMonth` function. 
I set the break point:

[image]

and as you can see, the function is undefined and I do not know why.

At the beginning of the `onInit` function, I called the `_isDateType` function:

```
console.log(this._isDateType(new Date()));
```

and it supply the result as expected.

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the arrow syntax ...

```
_getLastDayOfMonth: (oBegin) => {
```

... with a normal [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```js
_getLastDayOfMonth: function(oBegin) { // or _getLastDayOfMonth(oBegin) {
  // this === Controller instance
}
```

By this, `_getLastDayOfMonth` can freely access other methods within the Controller instance.

## Why it didn't work with arrow function

- Arrow functions do not create their own `this`, which is why `this` usually refers to the context from the arrow function's lexical scope. Therefore, arrow functions, in general, should not be used as methods.

  > Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this`, `arguments`, or `super`, and should not be used as methods. <sup>[[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)</sup>
- In the above case, `this` was referring to the `window` object when `BaseController.extend` was called. Calling `this._isDateType` inside the arrow function was equivalent to `window._isDateType`.

Answer (score 0):

The element this can be used inside a function to get the temporary value of the element. To use the `_isDateType` method you should  create an attribute  inside the method and fill it with the 'this' value.

```
return BaseController.extend("ch.micarna.weightprotocol.controller.Calendar", {
var temp= null;
onInit: function () {
  temp = this;
  console.log(temp._isDateType(new Date()));

  let oHbox = temp.byId("calendar-container");

  let oTodayDate = new Date();
  let oEndDate = temp._getLastDayOfMonth(oTodayDate);

},

_getLastDayOfMonth: (oBegin) => {

  if (temp._isDateType(oBegin)) {
    throw new TypeError("The given parameter is not type of date.");
  }
  return new Date(oBegin.getFullYear(), oBegin.getMonth() + 1, 0);
},

_isDateType: (oDate) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(oDate) === "[object Date]";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you cannot do is refer to a property of an "under construction" object from elsewhere in the object literal syntax. In cases where you want to do that, you do need one or more separate assignment statements.

For example, move your code as follows:

```
var temp = BaseController.extend("ch.micarna.weightprotocol.controller.Calendar", {

onInit: function () {

  console.log(this._isDateType(new Date()));

  let oHbox = this.byId("calendar-container");

  let oTodayDate = new Date();
  let oEndDate = this._getLastDayOfMonth(oTodayDate);

}

});

temp._isDateType = (oDate) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(oDate) === "[object Date]";
};

temp._getLastDayOfMonth = (oBegin) => {

  if (this._isDateType(oBegin)) {
    throw new TypeError("The given parameter is not type of date.");
  }
  return new Date(oBegin.getFullYear(), oBegin.getMonth() + 1, 0);
}

return temp;
```

The idea is to split function assignments into several statements;