# why is my arrow function erroring as 'not a function'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the readline package to prompt the user for a series of inputs.  Its my understanding I have pass in each prompt as a callback so I made them arrow functions, as done in the `go()` function.  The program flow is getLowerBounds() to getUpperBounds() to close().

What happens is I get the prompt for the first input `Enter starting range: [4000000] ->`. After entering my input, I get the error `TypeError: nextFn is not a function`.

Here's my code:

```
import * as Readline from 'readline';

class InputPrompts {
    private readline: any;

    constructor() {
        this.readline = Readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });
    }

    private getInput(message: string, def: any, nextFn?: any) {
        this.readline.question(`${message}: [${def}] -> `, (answer) => {
            if (nextFn === null) return;
            nextFn(answer);
        });
    }

    public getLowerBounds(next?: any) {
        this.getInput('Enter starting range', 4000000);
    }

    public getUpperBounds(next?: any) {
        this.getInput('Enter top of the range', 8999999);
    }

    public go() {
        const endFn = (answer) => {
            this.readline.close();
        };

        const upperFn = (answer) => {
            console.log(`upperFn() got ${answer}`);
            this.getUpperBounds(endFn);
        };

        this.getLowerBounds(upperFn);
    }
}

function run() {
    new InputPrompts().go();
}

run();
```

I am not sure what is wrong.  I have looked this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096581/uncaught-typeerror-this-isdatetype-is-not-a-function-within-arrow-function). I replaced arrow function bodies with `console.log()` and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you're not passing the `next` parameters in `getUpperBounds`/`getLowerBounds` to the `getInput` call
- when not passing an optional argument, the value will be `undefined`. Your `getInput` method is only testing against `null`.

I'd suggest doing

```
private getInput(message: string, def: any, next: (answer: string) -> void = () => {}) {
    this.readline.question(`${message}: [${def}] -> `, next);
}

public getLowerBounds(next?: (answer: string) -> void) {
    this.getInput('Enter starting range', 4000000, next);
}

public getUpperBounds(next?: (answer: string) -> void) {
    this.getInput('Enter top of the range', 8999999, next);
}
```

Comment: That's embarrassing.  The first bullet point was it.  Thank you for finding my mistake.